# Error message "Cannot index array with string 'Title'" when parsing JSON data with jq

Tags: jq

```
{
    "content": [
    {
        "Title": "abc",
        "brand": "xyz",
        "size": "5 g",
        "date": "2019-01-01",
        "details": {
            "Temperature": [
            {
                "value": "90",
                "characteristics":"Normal"
            },
            {
                "value":"100",
                "characteristics":"high"
            },

            {
                "value":"80",
                "characteristics":"low"
            }
            ],

            "certifications": [
            {
                "value": "based",
                "characteristics":"pass"
            },

            {
                "value": "50",
                "characteristics":"failed"
            }
            ]
        },

         "formats": {
            "city": "NYC",
            "id": "007",
            "manufacture":""
            },
        "innerDetails": [
        {
            "contains": "abc",
            "panel":"xyz",
            "values":[
                {
                    "name":"abc",
                    "value":"10"
                },
                {
                    "name":"xyz",
                    "value":"20"
                }
                ]
            }
        ]
}
]
}
```

I have tried the below approach, but getting the error

> Cannot index array with string "Title"

```
jq -r '.content[]|[.Title,.brand,.characteristics,.value]' $jsonfile.
```

I was trying on the same line with other sections, but getting the same error.

How do I solve this issue?

Expected output:

```
abc,xyz,90,Normal.
abc,xyz,100,high.
abc,xyz,80,low
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are not getting `Cannot index array with string "Title"` with that command, you are getting

```
[
  "abc",
  "xyz",
  null,
  null
]
```

since there is no `characteristics` or `value` key in the objects of the `contents` array (they are keys in the `.details.Temperature` sub-array).

The command that *would* have given you that message is:

```
jq -r '.[] | [.Title,.brand,.characteristics,.value]' "$jsonfile"
```

or

```
jq -r '.content | [.Title,.brand,.characteristics,.value]' "$jsonfile"
```

Missing out the `content` key lookup, or failing to get the elements of the `content` array, yields an array of one object rather than the object itself.  And you can't index an array with a string.

---

Assuming you want CSV output:

```
$ jq -r '.content[] | .details.Temperature[] as $t | [.Title,.brand,$t.value,$t.characteristics] | @csv' file.json
"abc","xyz","90","Normal"
"abc","xyz","100","high"
"abc","xyz","80","low"
```

The `<object(s)> as <variable>` acts like a loop in `jq`, so what happens here is that `$t` will be assigned each element of `.details.Temperature[]` in turn, and for each element, a new array is constructed.  The array is passed through `@csv` which will output CSV-formatted rows.

`jq` will always double quote the fields of its CSV output.  To get rid of *unnecessary* quotes:

```
jq -r '...as above...' file.json | csvformat
```

(`csvformat` is part of [`csvkit`](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/))

Or, you may want to use `@tsv` in place of `@csv` to get tab-delimited output instead.

Comment: Kusal Thank you for your inputs. I am using above thing with for loop. details below.                                                                                                                                         for field in Temperature certifications ; do
    echo $field ::
    jq --arg field "$field" -r '
      .content[] | .details."$field"[] as $t | [.Title,.brand,$t.value,$t.characteristics] | @csv' file.json
done. but getting "jq: error: try .["field"] instead of .field for unusually named fields at <top-level>, line 1:"

Comment: I got this, I was not able to correlate and was putting .details.$[field] or .details."$field". Now I have changed that to .details[$field][] and it's working fine now.

Comment: @sam Sorry, I was elsewhere.  Yes, `.details[$field][]` or `.["details"][$field][]` is the correct syntax.

Comment: I have up-voted and thank you for your support.

Comment: Kusal,sorry for bothering you again. Is it possible to get the content main values without giving the name of fields."Title","brand","size","date" values. something like     jq -r .content[] | and it give me all the main values as mentioned above.