# how to install csvkit in bash

Tags: software-installation, mingw, csvkit

Kusalananda nicely recommends using `csvformat` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to format `jq` `@csv` into a csv format without double quotes `"` [answering how to parse json with jq](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/506790/530603).

This answer does not seem to involve the use of python. But the csvkit [installation tutorial](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/1_getting_started.html#installing-csvkit) and its [installation troubleshooting](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tricks.html#troubleshooting) do seem to rely on, perhaps require, the use of python. This makes me, a newbie, confused:

Is it possible to install csvkit in git bash without using python (read: open spyder or anaconda, let's say)? How?

**Edit.** MINGW64 (git bash) displays `bash: pip: command not found`. Same for `conda`.
How do you recommend moving on from there?

python is installed, pip.exe being in `...\Anaconda\Scripts`. There are several suggested solutions on other sites e.g. in various ways adding the dir of pip.exe to PATH [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/6318156/adding-python-to-path-on-windows) and [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/question/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three steps installed csvkit, in reverse order:

3. csvkit worked in git bash (mingw64) as indicated by

`csvformat --help`

2. after installation using pip (pip was installed by Anaconda)

`pip install csvkit`

1. made possible by adding the directory of pip.exe to PATH in the running session

`PATH=$PATH:~/Anaconda3/Scripts`

A more permanent solution requires adding the directory of pip.exe to e.g. .bashrc or .bash_profile, see e.g.:

[How to correctly add a path to PATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/530603)

[Extend $PATH variable in git bash under Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980107/extend-path-variable-in-git-bash-under-windows)

Comment: OP is not under windows.

Comment: @number9 please explain :-)

Answer (score 6):

The csvkit tools are all written in Python.

Depending on what Unix you're running, you may also find csvkit available as a ready-made package, so you don't have to worry about *explicitly* dealing with `pip` or Python packages.  On Debian-based Linuxes, the package is called `csvkit` (so use `apt install csvkit`). The Homebrew package manager for macOS also has a `csvkit` package (so use `brew install csvkit`).

Installing csvkit as a ready-made package from your ordinary software distributor is the easiest way to install csvkit.  This installs the software and its dependencies as an integrated part of your system and will keep it up to date as any other software that you have installed in the same way.

However, it's unlikely that the developers of csvkit are the ones who also package the software for your system (it's done by package maintainers associated with the Unix or Linux you are using), so their only surefire way to recommend the installation of the utilities is using `pip`, the Python package manager.

Using `pip` to install csvkit as described in the documents that you link to is only *neccesary* if your ordinary package manager does not have csvkit (as on e.g. OpenBSD), if you need a particular version of csvkit that is not provided in any other way, or if you need to install the software as an unprivileged user (use `pip` with its `--user` option).

Care should be taken when installing software by other means than through the use of the ordinary package manager to avoid collisions between installed files. It's, therefore, a good idea to set up a virtualenv environment and install csvkit in there, [as suggested by the csvkit developers](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/1_getting_started.html?highlight=virtualenv#installing-csvkit).

Comment: +1.  Also worth noting: if a packaged version is available for your distro then install the packaged version - it will have all the right dependencies to be properly integrated into the OS, and upgrades will be automatically handled.  Installing stuff with pip will require manual upgrading and dependency management in future.  It's nice to have tools like `pip` available, but distro packages are inherently better.  Also, some distros have tools to automate creation of distro packages from python packages - e.g. debian's `py2dsc` (from [python3-stdeb](https://github.com/astraw/stdeb)`)

Comment: Some people might not want to use 260 MB just to have pip installed and `apt install csvkit` is a good option, however, by default, it is still a 190 MB installation, so maybe simply running `apt install python3 python3-setuptools` and installing manually the latest version (1.0.7) of csvkit is a better option (`python3 setup.py install`). Bonus points if you create a virtual environment for your python stuff, just to prevent potential conflicts later on (which are not precisely uncommon when installing distro packages).

Comment: @JohanAndresen If you already have Anaconda installed, simply run `conda install csvkit`. I used Anaconda (actually, miniconda) because I work with python files regularly, however, that wouldn't be my first suggestion for people that only want to use a single python package given the huge number of libraries that anaconda preinstalls by default.

Comment: And yes, you can update your question to clarify the issue, although most people won't receive notifications of the changes unless they are following your question.

Comment: Thanks all. Sorry @RobertSmith, you were so fast I did not get to edit my comment: MINGW64 displays `bash: pip: command not found`. **Same for conda**. How do you recommend moving on from there? python is installed, pip.exe being in `...\Anaconda\Scripts`. There are several suggested solutions on other sites e.g. in various ways adding the dir of pip.exe to PATH [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/45980107/extend-path-variable-in-git-bash-under-windows) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash).

Comment: @JohanAndresen Sorry, but since I don't have access to a Windows system running mingw64, I can't say much about how to install packages on that system. Robert mentioned that you may possibly use `conda install csvkit`, but I obviously have no way of testing this myself.

Comment: @JohanAndresen I don't have a Windows system either, however, are you sure you're activating your conda environment?  If so, can you simply install csvkit with conda? If that works, you can forget about installing pip.

Comment: @RobertSmith do you suggest I run Anaconda prompt? (I would like to use bit bash). Or what do you mean by "activating your conda environment"? After I `pip install csvkit`, and `csvkit --help`, Anaconda prompt displays `'csvkit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

Comment: Upon running `$ csvkit --help` mingw64 displays `bash: csvkit: command not found`. Have you any idea what to do? I added `Anaconda\Scripts\` to PATH such that `pip` installed csvkit, which appears in the output of `pip list` "listing installed packages".

Comment: @JohanAndresen It was `csvformat` you wanted to use, wasn't it? There is no separate `csvkit` command.

Comment: You are right, @Kusalanda. I also noticed this mistake, and it became clear that the installation worked. I wrote an answer to make this clear. Delightful!